# In DateTime only 62 of 64 bits are used. Negative values are not in the spec. How do I represent dates BC?

Tags: .net, datetime

Using VB.NET:

```
Debug.Print(DateTime.MinValue.ToString)
Debug.Print(DateTime.MaxValue.ToString)
Debug.Print(DateTime.MinValue.Ticks.ToString)
Debug.Print(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks.ToString)
```

I obtain:

```
01-01-0001
31-12-9999
0
3155378975999999999
```

The max value in binary reads `0010 1011 1100 1010 0010 1000 0111 0101 1111 0100 0011 0111 0011 1111 1111 1111‬`.

Just 62 of 64 bits were used.

(1) Why wasn't the MSB used to provide dates easily reaching as far back as 10000 BC?

(2) Are these 2 bits reserved for something I am not aware of?

(3) To assign dates BC and do arithmetics with them, do I have no choice other than defining a new datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top two bits are used for the "kind":

- Local
- UTC
- Unspecified
- "Local with special knowledge for ambiguous cases"

See [my blog post for more information on this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/). Admittedly the "kind" was only introduced in .NET 1.1 (IIRC); I suspect the range limit before then was simply a matter of pragmatism. There are all kinds of practical issues that arise when you decide to handle values earlier than 0001-01-01, and I suspect the .NET designers considered that those issues would hurt more developers than the number of developers who *need* the larger date range.

In terms of how to deal with earlier dates, I would strongly advise *against* writing your own date/time code unless you absolutely have to. I would personally recommend my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library. That [handles](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/userguide/range) dates in the range [9999BC, 9999AD], as well as having nanosecond precision for times, and support for the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).